# JavaScript Code after ajax request not working in server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having an ajax request that puts some data in a PHP file, then PHP files generate HTML content with some JavaScript Code. Javascript codes include Google's chart library too. So the chart is even not working. (Basically ajax sends some data to a php files, php file generates the graph)

**ajax request**

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'report.php',
    data: { url: '<?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>' }, 
    success: function (data) { 
        var response = data;
        $('#to_change').html(data);
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
});
```

**on report.php**

```
<div id="score">0</div>
<div id="chart1" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "<?php echo $sum_score; ?>";
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart","bar"]});
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Pac Man', 'Percentage'],
              ['Analyzer Score', <?php echo $sum_score; ?>],
              ['', <?php echo 100-$sum_score; ?>],
              ['', 100]
            ]);

            var options = {
              pieHole: 0.5,
              tooltip: {text: 'value'},
              legend: 'none',
              width: 500,
              pieSliceText: 'none',
              pieStartAngle: 270,
              slices: {
                0: { color: '<?php echo $color; ?>' },
                1: { color: '#d8d8d8'},
                2: { color: 'yellow'}
              }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart1'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
    </script>
```

The one thing i wonder is its working perfectly in localhost!

Comment: you should use `url: baseURL +'report.php'` include `baseURL` what error you are getting in your browser console??

Comment: seems cors error is there....

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I checked the response using firebug. The response data is correct. No errors. Only problem is javascript codes not working after loading to browser

Comment: @GijoVarghese i can not get you `not working after loading to browser `

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I mean those js codes loaded by ajax are not running

Comment: you should write all code for `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);` out side this partial php file and put it on main page.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi but the of google charts variables are changed in report.php. So i cannot put those codes in main page

Comment: try by calling `drawChart();` after `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);` their is not load event fires for partial views. you have to call events. @GijoVarghese

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102477/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-gijo-varghese).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem solved. There were no errors in the code. I have integrated CloudFlare CDN. They implemented a feature called rocked loader for javascript files. That's why it was not working. I turned it off. Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

insead of data: `{ url: '<?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>' }` use other variable like

data: `{ data_url: '<?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>' }`

Comment: @Yuvaj R what difference will that make?

Answer (score 0):

**This show me the diagram** What is the problem?

I don't see in your code

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Chart working perfect!!

`Parth Trivedi` you not so smart so you do

`Parth Trivedi let it as it is.as you can see how many bad answers are their... :D regarding url :D :D :D`  **Parth Trivedi write in Chat room**

link https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102477/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-gijo-varghese

```
   <? $color='black';
   $sum_score=5;
    echo 100-intval($sum_score); 

   ?>



   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <div id="score">0</div>
   <div id="chart1" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "<?php echo $sum_score; ?>";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart","bar"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Pac Man', 'Percentage'],
          ['Analyzer Score', <?php echo $sum_score; ?>],
          ['', <?php echo 100-$sum_score; ?>],
          ['', 100]
        ]);

        var options = {
          pieHole: 0.5,
          tooltip: {text: 'value'},
          legend: 'none',
          width: 500,
          pieSliceText: 'none',
          pieStartAngle: 270,
          slices: {
            0: { color: '<?php echo $color; ?>' },
            1: { color: '#d8d8d8'},
            2: { color: 'yellow'}
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart1'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
 </script>
```

Comment: its a partial view loaded by ajax. Not included js in this view. It included in main view. Make discussion in chat only. Don't put it in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to ensure first that all the DOM elements are successfully loaded. Regardless where you put your `<script>` codes (at the start, middle, end), the browser always loads it first.

I suggest that you use **jquery**. Then do the ff in your `<script>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function(){
      // your js codes... just wrap them here
      // codes here are executed right after all html elements are rendered by browser
   });
</script>
```